# highest priority notification without popup

Tags: android, android-notifications

**I need notification that appears at the top of notification drawer (or lock screen) but doesn't disturb the user with popup** (-highest priority but not heads up notification)

what I've tried:

- use fully custom notification and `setCustomHeadsUpContentView()` with empty layout.
- add dummy empty heads up notification to hide the current

They both worked on only some of the devices and not perfectly

I will be happy for any solution

Comment: Please show us the dummy layout you build for this. Also have you found alternative solution?